# How to change .csv.gz encoding to utf-8

Tags: python, r, csv, text, encoding

I want to user either R or Python to convert .csv.gz file to utf-8 encoding. How can I do this directly? I am not able find any comprehensive guide as how to do this.

My best attempt was to read .csv.gz file with `csv.reader` in python:

```
csvFile = gzip.open('pracodawcy_20190611_5.csv.gz', 'rt', newline='')
reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
```

But later how to save it as csv with utf-8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very easily, it puts the file in a vector:

```
import gzip

### assuming the file is separated as you said
with gzip.open('input_file.csv.gz', 'rt', newline='\n') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

### to print the vector content
for v in content :
    print(v)

### to write to .csv.gz
with gzip.open('output.csv.gz', 'wb') as f:
for v in content :
    f.write(v.encode('utf-8'))
```

you can also lazy-open it line per line if it's too big with read() or for. There are a lot of examples here and in the web.

Comment: OK I know how to open but then how to properly save to .csv.gz format with utf-8?